# Error while executing .csh file :-> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to run a `.csh` file on Ubuntu 17.10 64bit. 
Whenever I try to execute the file using

```
~/MSCS/Thesis\ MSCS/trainingScript.csh
```

it gives me this error:

```
bash: /home/zahra/MSCS/Thesis MSCS/trainingScript.csh: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I have tried the solutions given in similar questions but no luck.

```
file ~/MSCS/Thesis\ MSCS/trainingScript.csh
```

gives me

```
/home/zahra/MSCS/Thesis MSCS/trainingScript.csh: C shell script, Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text executable, with CRLF, CR line terminators
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C Shell is more common in BSD unix, as Ubuntu being a GNU/Linux uses BASH from the GNU project.

Ideally Shell script contain a shebang (`#!/bin/csh`) at the start of the file that tells the system how to run it, however your system may not have C Shell there.

Ensure your system has CSH loaded (it's in universe so you'll need that repository  enabled)  Refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/csh

To manually run the script (esp. if shebang isn't in script), use

```
csh -f trainingScript.csh
```

Comment: the `-f` is probably unnecessary